# How do I view multiple pictures in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, photos

Ok so back in Windows 7, there was a program called Windows Fax Viewer or Windows Gallery.  Something like that, it was the default image viewer.  It let me view the next picture in the folder.  The bad thing was that it didn't keep the view size (i.e. 100% zoom) on the next image.

So here comes Office Picture Manager in Office 2010.  I can view the next image at 100% (this was good for reading comics).

So I upgrade to Windows 10 and the default "Photos" application seems to more like a basic photo editor than a viewer.

I downloaded Office 2016 and they removed Office Picture Manager...

Comment: It is possible to get back the old Windows Photo Viewer in windows 10. It's just hidden under some settings. I'll need to Google it, maybe, and I'll tell you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeking other programmes which display photos at 100% scale, than what Windows offers, use IrfanView. And from `Options` -> `Properties/Settings`, pick the tab `Full Screen / Slideshow` and set the radio button to `Show images/movies with the original size`. Confirm your changes. You can use Left and Right arrows on your keyboard to switch between photos once you open one.

Optional: set IrfanView to be the default photo viewer.

Comment: XNview too, old simple versions of acdsee, once you get used to 3rd party MS replacements you will wonder why you bothered :-)  Rant: just more things they could have vastly improved in the OS as goals to get people to buy it.

Answer (score 3):

You can right-click any image, and choose `Properties`. In the `General` tab, click `Change`, where it says `Open With`. A list with available photo applications should show up, including Windows Gallery, and Windows Photo Viewer.

The one you choose, will be the default application for viewing the kind of photo you right-clicked in the beginning. Of course you have to do this for every format of images you have on your computer.

Comment: @Jack, please accept either of the two answers, the one that helped more, if the problem is solved. The question will then be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Microsoft Photos to view multiple pictures at once in Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use MulimgViewer. (This is my repository).

MulimgViewer is a multi-image viewer that can open multiple images in one interface, which is convenient for image comparison and image stitching.

MulimgViewer supports sequential and parallel mode to display image.

MulimgViewer is implemented in python and currently provides Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 versions.

Future: The parallel zoom function of the picture is being realized and I believe it will be released soon.

GitHub: https://github.com/nachifur/MulimgViewer

Wiki: https://github.com/nachifur/MulimgViewer/wiki

Any partners with ideas can work together to develop MulimgViewer.
[MulimgViewer GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWcF6.jpg)